# Formatting a date with uncertain data

Tags: php, date, datetime, formatting, date-formatting

A quick search didn't return any results that seemed to fit what I was looking for so I come here asking for your help.

I am working on formatting a birthday. The problem is, the use has the ability to enter only some (or none) of the data. It is stored separately as day, month, and year.

Basically, based on the data present will determine how the date will be formatted and displayed back to the user.

My approach is:

```
#prepare birthday
        $bday = new DateTime();
        $bday->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
        $bday->setDate($row->birth_year,$row->birth_month,$row->birth_day);

        if($row->birth_month && $row->birth_year && $row->birth_day){
            //Full birthday entered
            $display_bday = $bday->format('F j, Y');    
        } elseif($row->birth_month && !$row->birth_year && !$row->birth_day){
            //Only a month
            $display_bday = $bday->format('F');     
        } elseif($row->birth_month && $row->birth_year && !$row->birth_day){
            //Only Month and year
            $display_bday = $bday->format('F, Y');  
        }
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this task. I guess I figure there has to be a better way. Thanks in advance. If I need to clarify anything please just ask!

edit: removed unnecessary code

Answer (score 0):

Your code could output invalid date since you are not filtering input when setting up a `DateTime` object. When the `$row->birth_day` equals `0`, the `DateTime` object will move back to previous month (last date).

So, I suggest to consider that:

```
$display_bday = null;
if ($row->birth_month) {
  if ($row->birth_year) {
    if ($row->birth_day) {
      // day, month, and year
      $display_bday = date('F j, Y', strtotime("$row->birth_year-$row->birth_month-$row->birth_day"));
    } else {
      // month and year
      $display_bday = date('F, Y', strtotime("$row->birth_year-$row->birth_month-01"));
    }
  } else {
    if ($row->birth_day) {
      // day and month
      $display_bday = date('F j', strtotime("2016-$row->birth_month-$row->birth_day"));
    } else {
      // month only
      $display_bday = date('F', strtotime("2016-$row->birth_month-01"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion and will take it into consideration. The issue with the code you provided, however, is that if there is no birth month then none of the code will process. I do like this approach better though.

Comment: Yes, you could add some logic there to consider if month is not set. When month is not set, try looking year value, display it when exists.